# SN76489 - Ready pin not working?

Tags: audio

I'm testing the **SN76489AN** chip with Arduino and I'm able to play the 3 tones I want etc BUT I don't understand why the READY pin is not working? The datasheet says the pin goes high when the chip is ready and low when it's busy with processing a command. But the **READY pin is always low!** I've got 2 brand new pieces of the chip and they both act this way. I've even tried to pull-up this pin but it didn't help. I see everyone is just using `delayMicroseconds` in their examples, so I guess it is a common problem but it's just strange... Is it a bug in the chip or what? Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a link to the datasheet for the chip. How do you know the pin is always low? Do you measure it (and if so, how?), or is it a side-effect of the code? If the latter, please post your code using the code formatting markdown (four leading spaces). For help see [Markdown help](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help). You should be able to do this by selecting the code and pressing `Ctrl+K` to have your browser do this for you.

Comment: READY is open-collector. It will require a pullup-resistor. Test circuit in datasheet shows a 2kohm resistor.

Comment: Oh, so the pull-up idea was good, but I just used too big resistor. I haven't noticed the 2K resistor in the test circuit! Thanks @Mikael! (sorry I can't give you +1 here yet). Unfortunately this method is not much fuster than the version with delay. PS: @Nick, I have measured it when the chip was idle (when it should by high) and I am actively waiting for the pin to become high in a `while` loop.

Comment: @MikaelPatel, if you will copy your comment as an answer then I will be able to mark it as answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The READY signal is [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector). It will therefore require a pullup-resistor. Test circuit in datasheet shows a 2 kohm resistor. You could try with that. Alternatively use the internal pullup resistor on the input pin but this may be too large (weak).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but the mistake was that I had missed the clock pin on my breadboard by one row, so there was no clock signal.